# How to do a JSON webservice

Tags: json, web-services

I need to create a webservice that will be used in iOS, Windows Phone and Android apps.

I've found many tutorials on the Internet but no one uses real JSON files.
I have an example of what I mean:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=tiste&count=2

Is it better to use a web service like Twitter or can we use only headers in PHP?
If it's the first, how can I do it?

Finally, is JSON the most suitable option for web service communication?

Answer (score 1):

Most contemporary web apps are built around an api - they are called api-centric. Twitter is one of them. You are not the only one who needs to create a web frontend and apps for mobile platforms. Having an api for all those platforms is going to save you a lot of time.

This field is developing rapidly now. There are many frameworks(both client and server side) to choose from. Since you are not telling us which technology/programming language you are going to use, i can only suggest you to google an api-centric or a rest framework. If you extend your question, i'll give a more specific answer.

Meanwhile you can read the following general articles...

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-an-api-centric-web-application/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth
- http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/09/23/short-list-of-restful-api-frameworks-for-php/

Comment: Thank a lot ! But do you know how twitter do to have a json extension to their API ? Because with example you gave me, they use a php extension but with a json headers.

Comment: Language choice is up to you. Any language can output json: php, jsp, asp, python, ruby, perl.... Twitter is built using ruby as far as i know.